# Node not downloading through Homebrew, Terminal stuck on this line of code with no update

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew

I downloaded Homebrew on macOS 10.12. It seemed to have downloaded successfully, but node is not downloaded through Homebrew. As I try to redownload node, I get this warning that homebrew doesn't support macOS 10.12, despite the first time success message I got that Homebrew downloaded successfully. My question is why Node isn't downloaded, and how I can get past this stage to download? The first time downloading, the Terminal got stuck at this one stage without much update for a long time so i exited and retried. The second and consequent times I tried "brew install node" have all been the same result (output below):

```
brew -v
Homebrew 2.1.14
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision fc71; last commit 2019-10-15)
brew install node
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
cayley          ical-buddy      kubernetes-cli  mame            pgrouting
glooctl         kpcli           lerna           mypy            youtube-dl

Warning: You are using macOS 10.12.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Discourse, Twitter or IRC. You are responsible for resolving any issues you
experience while you are running this old version.

==> Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.12.0/node-v12.12.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/Derek/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/36baa40ca2c3606ecc0219babae57f811a8f1b57ef290628efdc4fd555ee5f4e--node-v12.12.0.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.12.0 --without-npm --with-int==> make install
```

---

At this point, it just gets stuck and nothing happens. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install `node`, Homebrew try to download a pre-built package and install it for you. The problem is, Homebrew only provide **pre-built packages for the latest 3 version of macOS**. For the time being, prebuilt pkg `node` is only provided on macOS 10.13, 10.14, 10.15.

Cause Homebrew doesn't provide a pre-built pkg for macOS 10.12, the package will be built from source. That explains why your shell got stuck. The output word `./configure` and `make install` are enough to let users realize it's **compiling a package in the background** as well.

Just wait patiently for the `make install` to be done.